# Black screen around Virtualbox VM in fullscreen mode (Guest additions installed)

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, fullscreen

I installed Windows 10 on a virtual machine, and everything is working fine. But when I go into fullscreen mode, the size doesn't change, and I get a black screen around the display. Some people suggested that I install the guest additions, so I did. I downloaded the file and inserted it. This did not change anything. I still get a black screen around the VM. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why did I get a -1? I am willing to improve the question if necessary.

Comment: This appears to be a Windows issue based on the subject being a Windows VM and not Ubuntu.  This is offtopic.  (Likely why you got a down vote).

Comment: @ThomasWard It *is* a Windows based issue, that presents as an Ubuntu issue, which is why it *is* an appropriate question.

Comment: @ThomasWard (Actually I think it's a VirtualBox question which may or may not be a Windows question.)  Downgrading a question without an explanation may not be required, but it adds to the perception that Stack Overflow is an unwelcoming or hostile place.  (Personally I think it's a form of bullying) It's not helpful to someone trying to learn.  If the down vote had come with a note: "This is a virtualbox issue, and has been answered here ..." it would be helpful.  This article is spot on - https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Answer (score 24):

The guest additions cd needs installed within the client. You can do this from the client toolbar. Devices -> Insert guest additions CD image...

That will mount the guest additions cd image. Click on it to run it. Let it install. It will then reboot the guest operating system. When the guest restarts and you log back in you will be able to go full screen and the resolution will adjust automatically. You can scale the window whatever way you want by dragging the corners of guest window and it will auto adjust to whatever that resolution is.

Comment: This answer deserves the most votes. After following these steps, Windows will always fill the entire window without needing to modify settings in either the guest or the host.

Comment: Totally agree with @trebormf. This is the correct answer

Comment: At first I found the display to appear slightly 'soft'. After checking the vm display settings I notice that the scale value was 101%. After correcting this to 100% I now have a good sharp display

Comment: It happened to me after a windows update, when Guest Additions was already installed. Going out of an into full screen mode again (right-ctrl + f, right-ctrl + f) solved the problem (more or less what is in the second paragraph, but without mouse).

Comment: In my case there was no optical drive attached to my VM.  I had to go to Settings -> Storage to add one before I could insert the disk

Comment: I just changed the resolution inside my Ubuntu VM and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably the resolution in Virtualbox does not match your monitor resolution. Try to change the resolution inside the virtual machine.

Comment: How do I achieve this?

Comment: Inside Windows 10 set the resolution matching your monitor.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Unfortunately, the highest resolution available is 1600x1200.  Also, in that resolution, my mouse doesn't go above a certain level.  Is there anyway to add a custom resolution? And is there anyway to fix this mouse problem?

Comment: Check which monitor is being emulated by guest additions. The 1600x1200 might be limitation of the additions. Check if there are additions for hi-res displays.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. You simply execute this command in the terminal: `VBoxManage setextradata "VMName" CustomVideoMode1 1920x1080x32`

Comment: @RahulMookooji Thanks, this solved the problem for me!

Comment: @RahulMukherji's answer worked. Just replaced "VMName" with my VM's actual name and after windows booted up, went and selected the 1920x1080 resolution in Windows Display Settings.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and did the following (with the Windows 10 VM stopped):

1. In the manager right-click and choose `settings` for the Windows 10 VM
2. Click on `User-Interface` options, at the bottom
3. Un-check/disable the option `Show in Full-Screen/Seamless`

This seemed too easy to possibly fix it, but it worked for me! No more black anomalies and such!

Answer (score 1):

you need to install an extension pack which is available at:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 0):

I found there's an option at the bottom right corner of the window.

[image: Screenshot] Pick the icon between the folder and recording icon. Choose 'Virtual Screen' in the dropdown then you'll be provided a whole bunch of resizing options. Pick one that fits your testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is less than 28 Mb of Video Memory has been allocated to the VM.
To adjust

1. Shutdown VM
2. Go to Settings / Display in VirtualBox
3. Adjust Video Memory slider so at least 28 Mb has been allocated.
4. Start up VM
5. My VM did not automatically switch to full screen until I moved it to my 2nd monitor and
   then back to my main screen.  I also right clicked on monitor icon on bottom of VM
   window and selected a couple of different resolutions - some adjusted others didn't.