# How to use Virtualbox in full screen?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 on Virtualbox on a Windows 10 host and I can't figure out how to get the screen to take up the full window. I've tried installing virtualbox-dkms and virtualbox-guest-dkms in the terminal and it didn't work.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/742692/black-screen-around-virtualbox-vm-in-fullscreen-mode-guest-additions-installed

Answer (score 3):

Before installing VirtualBox guest additions tool, run the commands below on the Ubuntu guest machine first.

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
```

After installing the packages above, restart and continue installing the Guest Additions Tool.

To install VirtualBox Guest Additions software on Ubuntu virtual machine operating systems, select the Devices from VirtualBox host application menu and click Insert Guest Additions CD image…
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8j3d.png)

Click run to begin installation.
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFBP4.png)

After installation is done reboot and you should be full screen.